# disable or hide scroll bar in textarea

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, css

How to disable or hide scroll bar in textarea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will hide all scrollbars for textareas.

```
textarea { 
overflow:hidden;
}
```

You can also use the id or class of the textarea to make it only that one:

```
textarea#txt {
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Keep in mind that these are **HIGHLY** unrecommended! If a user tries to type more than will fit inside your textarea they will not be able to see what they are writing. You have no idea how much people might want to write in a form.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`overflow:hidden` for the textarea.

See [**The overflow declaration**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html)

HTML

`<textarea id="txtArea" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>`

CSS

`#txtArea { overflow: hidden; }`

By doing this the user won't be able to view the text that is overflown. So better to make `overflow: auto`. This shows scrollbar where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Hiding the extra text is not recommended.. Why don't you try using jquery plugins for auto height textarea according to user input... Find below few links to scripts ...

1. [Auto Height](http://rodneyrehm.de/t/textarea.jquery.html)
2. [Auto Resize](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/)

Answer (score 0):

To hide it completely, use the following CSS:

overflow:hidden;

If all you are trying to do is remove the scrollbar showing on an empty text area but want to preserve the ability to scroll for larger blocks of text, then use:

overflow:auto;

Sorted.